# How do I open a Photoshop file in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign, image-quality, import

I would like to know how I can open a Photoshop file in InDesign.
I have been learning about all the features of InDesign, but now I want to start working on a document. I have made several copies of the document: I have a jpeg, a png and a psd document.
When I try to open these documents by just clicking *open* and then just choose the file. I get a default announcement, which says that InDesign doesn't support the file. 
I have also tried to place the file in an already made file: by choosing *place*, but in this case the quality is really bad.

I don't really need to work with the layers. If I can just have the content as a background on which I can work, I would manage.

Is there anyone that would know a solution to my problem?

Comment: This might help a bit: https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/how-to/get-started-indesign.html Seems you may be mistaken about the basic functionality of InDesign.

Comment: Welcome to **GD.SE** - please take a quick look around [tour] and [ask] and [answer] a question, to get an idea of our community and the kinds of questions which are appropriate here, and how to frame them in order to encourage the best responses. One thing we like to see is some basic effort at research, or some sense of what efforts you've made towards answering your issue yourself: as initially posed, your query doesn't seem to show that. Can you edit to show your own research efforts?

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to open JPG/PNG/PSD, InDesign does not edit these file types.

Place is ok. Start a new document and place the JPG/PNG/PSD files.

Quality is just a display setting. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The quality has already improved a lot. Is there a way to make it even better, because it still isn't the same as in the official document.